# Atributo de objeto pode ser preenchido com chamada de função? Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientação-a-objetos, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando transformar um arquivo .js em módulo para que eu possa acessá-lo em outro .js. Entao, esse arquivo que eu quero exportar precisa ser ele inteiro um objeto, certo?

Exemplo: Arquivo "database"

```
module.exports = {
        mongoose: require('mongoose')
        conecta: async function conectarDb() {
                const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/covid-database'
                await mongoose.connect(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
            /*...*/
         }
}
```

A dúvida é a seguinte:
Funciona eu preencher uma propriedade de um objeto com uma chamada de função (mongoose: require('mongoose')? No meu caso, ao dar "mongoose.conect(...)" na função da variável conecta definida logo abaixo, ele vai usar o atributo mongoose que eu defini logo acima?

Comment: Tem algum motivo em especial para isso? `this.mongoose` na função pode ser o que você precisa, apesar de que eu não vejo muita utilidade.

Comment: Isso resolveu. É que eu tenho dois arquivos: server.js e bd.js(esse onde tem o trecho acima). Estou usando express no server.js. O que eu quero fazer,é usar o bd.js como módulo em server.js, para que eu possa pegar objetos  recebidos do front-end pelo express, e salvá-los no banco de dados. Só que estou bem confuso. Pra isso eu uso mongoose. Mas estou confuso, não sei como lidar com assincronicidade nisso tudo.